# Tracking and closing actions being addressed by other working groups

Tags: tools, documentation

I work for a chain of hospitals which have annual inspections by the healthcare regulator. Following the inspections an action plan is created to address any issues identified during the inspection.

Some of the actions, for example, reducing patients' length of stay, are already being addressed by separate working groups and have existing comprehensive action plans. To avoid duplicating work, I am of the opinion that the action should be closed; however, I am wary of closing an action without any assurance that the issue is actually being resolved.

I am not sure if there is any best practice guidance on this. Would welcome your thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

Close the original action and open a new action to verify and validate the original action has been completed.